# How to apply coalesce expression in sort when using jpa specification

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I was working on building a querying solution with JPA using Specification.

I had sorting and pagination done as below using Spring Data and I'm using spring repository style methods for querying.

```
//Building specification with parameters
MySpecification specification=new MySpecification(List<SearchParameters>);
//Setting sort order and pagination
Sort sortOrder = new Sort(Direction.ASC,"<field_to_sort>");
PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(pageIndex, pageSize, sortOrder);
repository.findAll(specification, pageRequest);
```

Now I have a situation to sort fields based on a **coalesce expression**.
I understand spring data Sort can have only property names for sorting as show above.

I tried setting the sort order inside JPA specification but that didn't help either.

Is there anyway I can set the sort order as a coalesce expression while sticking on to JPA specification?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Spring Data 2.2, it still cannot call SQL functions using its own classes `Sort` or `Order` which makes it harder to use `Specification` and fully abstract from repository coding.

There is a workaround to use manually crafted `Specification` just for sorting purposes which will use JPA's `CriteriaBuilder` abilities to set sorting to resulting query.

Example of such `Specification` (using string-based attribute names for brevity, JPA metamodel classes could be used for this as well):

```
    public static Specification<Author> orderByPseudonymOrFullName() {
        return (user, cq, cb) -> {
            Expression<?> functionBasedAttributePath =
                    cb.lower(cb.coalesce(user.get("pseudonym"), user.get("fullName")));
            Expression<Author> pathToUserId = user.get("id");

            List<Order> orderByList = new ArrayList<>();
            orderByList.add(cb.asc(functionBasedAttributePath));
            // adding second sorting attribute to ensure stable order of users with same pseudonym
            orderByList.add(cb.asc(pathToUserId));

            cq.orderBy(orderByList);

            Specification<Author> emptySpec = Specification.where(null);//empty no-op specification
            return emptySpec.toPredicate(user, cq, cb);
        };
    }
```

And then use it as usual with `Sort.unsorted()` which will not be taken into account by Spring Data:

```
authorRepository.findAll(AuthorSpecifications.orderByPseudonymOrFullName(),
                             PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.unsorted()));
```

Link to GitHub repository with the example which contains a test to prove that it works: https://github.com/zzz3bra/customSortingWithSpringData

**Why does it work?**

`SimpleJpaRepository` class which is default repository implementation contains the next relevant code snippet:

```
    protected <S extends T> TypedQuery<S> getQuery(@Nullable Specification<S> spec, Class<S> domainClass, Sort sort) {

        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<S> query = builder.createQuery(domainClass);

        Root<S> root = applySpecificationToCriteria(spec, domainClass, query);
        query.select(root);

        if (sort.isSorted()) {
            query.orderBy(toOrders(sort, root, builder));
        }

        return applyRepositoryMethodMetadata(em.createQuery(query));
    }
```

So if `sort` is not sorted Spring Data will NOT call `query`'s `orderBy` method to override sorting already set by `applySpecificationToCriteria`.